# Populate node/add field from a entity reference field on the page?

Tags: entities

I have several sub-content types that are tied together in one content type via entity reference fields.

What I'd like to do is display the fields of each content type (instead of using a modal to add nodes of the sub-content types) so I installed the inline_entity_form, which allows me to do this. It displays the fields from all the sub-content types on the main content node/add screen. Because this is for a financial app, the client would like to see all the fields at the same time and enter them in one go by tabbing. The issue is that I lose the entity lookup feature so they can't select from existing content, like applicants.

What I thought would work is if I add another entity reference field above my primary entity reference fields so users can select existing content and would hide the fields of the corresponding sub-content-type.

Is there a more graceful way to approach this issue?